# Cant fix capitalization in Caesar's code exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, capitalization

Pretty new to programming so any help is greatly appreciated.

I am asked to make a function that returns a string with a given shift across the alphabet.
For example :`function caesar('a', 1)`  is supposed to return *b*.

The shift must retain capitalization, should not shift punctuation, should wrap around the alphabet and negative numbers should work.

I could make all the above work except the capitalization with the following:

```
const caesar = function(string,shift) {
    let stringSplitted = string.split('');
    let cypher = [];
    stringSplitted.map( letter => {
    if (letter === ' ' || letter === ',' || letter === '!' || letter === '.') {
     return cypher.push(letter);
   }
   let index = alphabet.indexOf(letter);
   if (index + shift > 25) {
    cypher.push(alphabet[(index + shift) - alphabet.length])
   }
   else if(index + (shift)<0) {
    return cypher.push(alphabet[(index + shift) + alphabet.length])
   }
   else
    cypher.push(alphabet[index + shift]);
 })
  return cypher.join('')
}
```

I know it's pretty messy.
Anytime i add capital letters to the string the result gets out of hand

I tried this

```
 if  (letter === letter.toLowerCase()) 
 return cypher.push(alphabet[index + shift].toUpperCase())
```

but it returns index and shift are not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the idea is that you use [ASCII codes](https://www.ascii-code.com/), instead of using a custom array for the alphabet, in which case the shift of value `1` for 'a' is 'b', and for 'A' is 'B'.

```js
const caesar = function(string, shift) {
  return string.split('').map( letter => {
    if (!/[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(letter)) { // Do the shift only for numbers and letters
      return letter;
    } else {
      return String.fromCharCode( letter.charCodeAt(0) + shift ); // return ascii code + shift
    }
  }).join('');
}

console.log(caesar('abAB', 1));

console.log(caesar('Lorem Ipsum 5', 2));
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have to look into this. Might u know why it wouldn't let me use uppercase in the second snippet? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the second snippet you were telling it in case the letter is lower case make it uppercase. Maybe you meant to do this if(letter === letter.toUpperCase()) return cypher.push(alphabet[index + shift].toUpperCase())